# GeoCoder throws "service not available" exception and geocoding api has usage limits

Tags: android, api, dictionary, geocoding, google-geocoder

I have seen similar question but none of them cleared my doubts.
GeoCoder.getFromLocationName() throws exception "service not available", only solution to that problem is to reboot your device. You can use Geocoding api but it has usage limits upto 25000 request per day. So, how other apps "Maps" and "Google Drive" are being running. Are they using Geocoding Api or "android.location.Geocoder" class?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Andriod. However, limit of Geocoding has 2,500 requests per day *(map loads per day is 25,000)*.

[Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits)

> Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500
>   requests per day. (User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up
>   to 100,000 requests per day.)

Google Maps API for Business starts from $10,000 per year as of 2013/08/26 (we've spoken with a person from Google a couple of days ago).